# Drupal: Cannot Access Uploaded Files in sites/default/files even though have permission 777

Tags: drupal

I have a drupal 7 site that can accept file uploads.  When I upload a file to test, it uploads fine, but I cannot download it.  When I click on the link in the post I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /sites/default/files/test file.pdf on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The default permissions upon upload are 644 (which should be readable as well), but I set the file permissions of the entire directory and subdirectory to 777 just to be on the safe side, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted `Deny from all` from .htaccess and it works